# IOS to support Facebook and Twitter sharing with logout option

Tags: iphone, ios

Application to share in Facebook and Twitter. i have tried Sharekit and facebook connect , able to share using it. but one problem facing is logout option, once i logged in not able logout and login with another user account... spent around one week for this...

what is best option for sharing with logout..

Application will support from IOS 4.3 to 6.1

Comment: Obviously you didn't read "Facebook Connect" carefully. There is a logout function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, you need to do two things

1. Find if your facebook wrapper is saving `accessToken` anywhere, if so remove it while logging out.
2. Remove cookies created for `Facebook` for your app by using following code..

   ```
   NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

   for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies])
   {

      NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
      NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
      if(domainRange.length > 0)
      {
         [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
      }
    }
   ```

Put the above code in your `Logout` function, it should work..

All the Best.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS6 please use following way to share on Facebook and Twitter :

```
-(void)ShareOnFacebook:(NSString *)strFacebook {

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [controller setInitialText:strFacebook];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strFacebook]];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"socialsharing-facebook-image.jpg"]];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
    return NSLog(@"%@",strFacebook);
}


-(void)ShareByTwitter:(NSString *)strTwitter {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]){
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:strTwitter];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    return NSLog(@"%@",strTwitter);
}
```

Comment: better option for below ios 6 devices for sharing